# Excel - copy/past range of cells if cell matches another cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't figure it out and am not very familiar with macros...

I have a workbook that has 5 sheets.
Sheet 1 - Has all employee name (2 cells - first and last name) with a lot of info
Sheet 2 to 4 - Has the employees divided up across these three sheets.

What I want to do:
If the employee first,last name on Sheet 1 matches the first,last name on sheet 2,3 or 4 then copy cells f,g,h,i,j,k,l from that row in sheet 1 to corresponding sheet 2-4 where name is found.

I hope that makes sense....  Basically, transfer/copy employee row from main sheet to sheet 2, 3, or 4.

If sheet1 a2 and b2=sheet2 b15 and c15 then copy sheet 1 f2,g2,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2 to sheet2's n15,o15,p15,q15,r15,s15,t15.

I've tried: =INDEX(RN!All_Original!F,MATCH(C3:D3,All_Original!C:D,0))
Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried? This question, in various iterations, is asked at least weekly on SO.  Please show us what you've tried so far, and what has/hasn't worked.  Do you really need to copy/paste the range, as it sounds like perhaps `VlookUp()` or `Index/Match` could do the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a very new to expanding my skills in excel.  I can try those two things again, but I couldn't get them to work.  I just get it messed up when trying to copy/past from the sheet 1 to the other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting there with the Index/Match you showed. I don't know how your data is laid out, but I think you're just a few small keys.

I have "Sheet1", which is this:
[image]

And in "Sheet2", we have:
[image]

So, we want to fill in, automatically, the "Fun Fact" for whoeever the person is, in this case Kobe Bryant.  You can use this formula:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$D$5,MATCH($A2&$B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,0),MATCH(C$1,Sheet1!$C$1:$D$1,0))`
(Enter as an array, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

If you change "Fun Fact" to "Favorite Food", it will update with "Italian".  You can use this formula on your other sheets.  Obviously, you will need to adjust the range(s) as necessary.

Edit: Note that the range sizes in the formula *must* be the same size, for it to work properly.  My last row is always `5`.  So, always use that range.

Comment: This is so helpful!  But I'm still getting stinking #N/A....  

For the example above is great!  The only difference is I would want to transfer both fun facts and favorite food to the next sheet.

The formula I have is =INDEX(All_Original!$F:$F,MATCH(RN!$C3&RN!$D3,All_Original!$C:$C&All_Original!$D:$D,0),MATCH(RN!O2,All_Original!F:F,0))

Comment: @dc64374 - It's a little tricky to tell - can you also include a screenshot/sample data of how it's laid out?  You're entering with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, correct?

Comment: Start troubleshooting - work backwards in the formula.  Replace the second `Match` with the header you expect. So in my example above, I'd try: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$D$5,MATCH($A2&$B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,0),MATCH("Fun Fact",Sheet1!$C$1:$D$1,0))` and if that returns N/A, do the same with the first match...try to whittle down where the error is thrown.  Or, go to Formulas --> Evaluate Formula, and step through it there, to see when the error occurs.

Comment: I am using ctrl+shift+Enter...trying to figure out how to put a screen shot on here....

Comment: I'm obviously not able to figure it out...but to describe it....

Sheet 1 (ALL)
A=ID
B=First Name
C=Last Name
D=blahblah
E=Blahblah
F=Choice 1
G=Choice2
all the way to L

So they have different numbers in the choice boxes ranking them.

I want to move this to Sheet 2 or 3 or 4 where I have name(B), last name (C)- cells e-n not relevant- and I want the info pasted in cells O-T.

I have around 500 names on the list....

Does that make sense?

Comment: @dc64374 - for screenshots, I suggest uploading to a public image site (such as Imgur.com), and share the link here in comments.

Comment: If you fill in a name, does the formula work? Try some fake names/data first to check. Also, make sure the header rows are exactly the same text (also be careful of leading/trailing spaces).

Comment: I had names in and just deleted them for the picture....and no, it wasn't working....

Comment: @dc64374 - What'd the Formula Evaluator show you? It should help show where the formula breaks.  Edit: **Oh**! I think I see - you need to use the same range size.  So you have some ranges going to row `500`, and some going to `530`. Use `530` for all the "last row parts".

Comment: I feel like I'm getting really close....

=INDEX(All!$F$3:$L$500,MATCH($C20&$D20,All!$C$3:$C518&All!$D$3:$D$500,0),MATCH‌​(O$3,All!$F$1:$L$1,0))

and now I'm getting #NAME?

Comment: @dc64374 - Ah, yay! Try this: `INDEX(All!$F$3:$L$518,MATCH($C20&$D20,All!$C$3:$C518&All!$D‌​$3:$D$518,0),MATCH‌​‌​(O$3,All!$F$1:$L$1,0‌​))` - again, make sure the range sizes are the same.

Comment: =INDEX(All!$F$3:$L$518,MATCH($C20&$D20,All!$C$3:$C518&All!$D$3:$D$518,0),MATCH‌‌​​‌​(O$2,All!$F$2:$L$2,0))

Still giving #name?  :(  i just don't know what I'm doing wrong.....

Comment: @dc64374 - hm, a `#NAME` error isn't necessarily the formula itself - but a name within that formula.  You do in fact have a sheet called "All", correct?  Not `All_Original` like your screenshot?

Comment: No, I changed it to All for simplicity.  

I've running the "Evaluate formula thing". It seems to be showing a problem with the first MATCH.  I tried changing it to names so it was Match("Jane"&"Doe",All!$C$3:$C$518,0).
I think it has something to do with  the part after jane doe, but I'm not sure what it would be....It looks like maybe it's putting in all the names from sheet one which doesn't give a match (or rather says 96)...

Comment: @dc64374 - So, if in the "All" sheet, you have "Jane" and "Doe" in `C3` and `D3` respectively, then have the same in your other sheet, use `INDEX(All!$F$3:$L$518,MATCH($C20&$D20,All!$C$3:$C518&All!$D‌‌​​$3:$D$518,0),MATCH‌‌​​‌​(O$3,All!$F$1:$L$‌​1,0‌​))`, it returns `#Name`? Can you post a screenshot (with actual data in the names cells), so I can see? I'm probably missing something obvious...Also, make ***positive*** your header cells are **exactly the same text** (I'd copy/paste to make sure). Again, a `#Name` error means you're referencing something that the function can't find.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Qejw84g      http://imgur.com/h2LvgH9      http://imgur.com/KacPNrd      http://imgur.com/BMgV3TB      http://imgur.com/TRhrPPt

Comment: @dc64374 - Can you please include a SS of the "All" sheet?

Comment: @dc64374 - I'll take a look. May be tomorrow though before I get back to you. This looks like it should work though.  One last thing, just try this: `=INDEX(All!$B$3:$B$518,MATCH($C20&$D20,All!$C$3:$C518&All!$D‌‌​‌​​$3:$D$518,0))` ...does that return the correct Employee ID?  Also, are there more than one "John Doe"?

Comment: Still having an issue in $D$3 at the end.  Only one Jane doe.  And ID numbers aren't on the second sheet (only the first).  And no worries about it being tomorrow.  I just need to have this figured out by the end of the week....Thank you so much for all your help!!!